# Modifying menu spacing in Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have created a Blazor app with menu on the left-hand side, which can also have submenus. Everything works well so far.

Would like to be able to control the spacing between items without screwing up or changing the default CSS very much.

In the screen shot below the first submenu is open with three menu options below. I don't think it looks very good that there is so much space between the submenu items. Cannot figure out how to smush them together without messing up other things.

[image]

```
<div class="top-row pl-4 navbar navbar-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Wire Desk</a>
</div>


<div class="@NavMenuCssClass">
    <ul class="nav flex-column">


        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" @onclick="() => ToggleNavMenu(NavSubmenu.None)" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
            </NavLink>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" @onclick="() => TogleSubmenu(NavSubmenu.First)">
                <span class="oi oi-arrow-thick-left" aria-hidden="true"></span> Incoming Funds Notifcation
            </NavLink>
        </li>

        @if (navSubmenu == NavSubmenu.First)
        {
            <li class="nav-item px-5">
                <NavLink class="nav-link" @onclick="() => ToggleNavMenu()" href="counter">
                    <span aria-hidden="true"></span> New Incoming Notification
                </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item px-5">
                <NavLink class="nav-link" @onclick="() => ToggleNavMenu()" href="fetchdata">
                    <span aria-hidden="true"></span> Unprocessed Deposits
                </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item px-5">
                <NavLink class="nav-link" @onclick="() => ToggleNavMenu()" href="fetchdata">
                    <span aria-hidden="true"></span> Processed Deposits
                </NavLink>
            </li>
        }


        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" @onclick="() => TogleSubmenu(NavSubmenu.Third)">
                <span class="oi oi-arrow-thick-left" aria-hidden="true"></span> Outgoing Funds Notifcation
            </NavLink>
        </li>

        @if (navSubmenu == NavSubmenu.Third)
        {
            <li class="nav-item px-5">
                <NavLink class="nav-link" @onclick="() => ToggleNavMenu()" href="counter">
                    <span aria-hidden="true"></span> New Outgoing Notification
                </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item px-5">
                <NavLink class="nav-link" @onclick="() => ToggleNavMenu()" href="fetchdata">
                    <span aria-hidden="true"></span> Other Items
                </NavLink>
            </li>
        }

        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" @onclick="() => TogleSubmenu(NavSubmenu.Second)">
                <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Customer Templates
            </NavLink>
        </li>

        @if (navSubmenu == NavSubmenu.Second)
        {
            <li class="nav-item px-5">
                <NavLink class="nav-link" @onclick="() => ToggleNavMenu()" href="all_templates">
                    <span class="oi oi-sun" aria-hidden="true"></span> All Templates
                </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item px-5">
                <NavLink class="nav-link" @onclick="() => ToggleNavMenu()" href="my_templates">
                    <span class="oi oi-person" aria-hidden="true"></span> My Templates
                </NavLink>
            </li>
        }


        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" @onclick="() => ToggleNavMenu()" href="my_approval_flow">
                <span class="oi oi-circle-check" aria-hidden="true"></span> My Approval Flow
            </NavLink>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" @onclick="() => ToggleNavMenu()" href="fiscal_year">
                <span class="oi oi-calendar aria-hidden="true"></span> Fiscal Year
            </NavLink>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" @onclick="() => ToggleNavMenu()" href="daily_reports">
                <span class="oi oi-signal" aria-hidden="true"></span> Daily Reports
            </NavLink>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>

@code {
    private enum NavSubmenu
    {
        None,
        First,
        Second,
        Third
    }

    private string NavMenuCssClass => collapseNavMenu ? "collapse" : null;
    private NavSubmenu navSubmenu = NavSubmenu.None;
    private bool collapseNavMenu = true;


    private void ToggleNavMenu(NavSubmenu? submenu = null)
    {
        collapseNavMenu = !collapseNavMenu;
        navSubmenu = submenu ?? navSubmenu;
    }

    private void TogleSubmenu(NavSubmenu submenu)
    {
        if (navSubmenu == submenu)
            navSubmenu = NavSubmenu.None;
        else
            navSubmenu = submenu;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Bryan

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the default blazor template, nav-link and nav-menu are styled by the template. App-level CSS is `app.css`.
*However*, if you using the latest version, it uses isolated CSS stylesheets. i.e. CSS defined for every component. Specifically, `nav-item` related CSS can be found under `NavMenu.razor` (click on the + icon it will show `NavMenu.razor.css` ).

```
.nav-item {
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

    .nav-item:first-of-type {
        padding-top: 1rem;
    }

    .nav-item:last-of-type {
        padding-bottom: 1rem;
    }

    .nav-item ::deep a {
        color: #d7d7d7;
        border-radius: 4px;
        height: 3rem;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        line-height: 3rem;
    }

.nav-item ::deep a.active {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
    color: white;
}

.nav-item ::deep a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    color: white;
}
```

You can add more specificity to this by adding more styles under nav-item (say nav-subitem or any other way in which you want to modify).

Answer (score 0):

Layout IS done by CSS.  If you want nav items X to be different than nav items Y, you need CSS rules for that.

You can make a sub-class in CSS and add that to your submenu items.:

```
.nav-item.submenu 
{
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-top:0;
    padding-bottom:0;
}
```

If you haven't used the Inspect tool in Chrome, you should.  You'll see that both `nav-item` and `nav-link` have quite a lot of padding.

Comment: Ben, Thank you for for reply. I do know about CSS and about inspection tools. I think that this may be an issue particular to Blazor. I tried adding the sub-class and adding it to the submenu items, but it didn't change anything. Blazor generates HTML/CSS/Javascript, which makes it difficult to tell where to change a CSS rule. Also, I am only been working with Blazor for 3 weeks.

Comment: CSS in Blazor is just CSS like anywhere else.  The only thing you need to know is to put your .css file in the wwwroot folder, and to add a reference to the file correctly.